# Sound effect not running cocos2d-x port for windows phone 8

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x

I wanted to add sound effects to a cocos2d-x game that I am porting to Windows Phone 8 port v2.0 for cocos2d-x.

I used this code :

`#include "SimpleAudioEngine.h"` 

`CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playEffect("sound_tap1.wav");`

But there was a linking error. So I searched the internet and found this:
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/25848?r=25939#message-25939

I added 'CocosDenshionWindowsPhone.lib;' to 'Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies' line.

But now it is throwing some exception at playEffect("sound_tap1.wav");
I have checked the file name is correct and the wav file is in the assets filter.

Any ideas?

Comment: so what does "some exception" say?

Comment: I found the solution. It is on the link to cocos2d-x forum above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Ok since there were no replies on this forum and I found a solution so I am posting it as answer so it can serve as a future reference for myself and be a guide to others.

The problem is in the relative and absolute path of the sound files.

 
`const char * path = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->fullPathFromRelativePath("sound.wav");
SoundEngine::sharedEngine()->playBackgroundMusic(path);`

If we use this utility, the problem goes away.

Also, we need to take care only to use .wav file formats while working with the WP8 Port of cocos2dx-v2.0

Credits:: Saud Ahmed (who helped me figure out the problem)